# Evaluate orientationEvent at onload?

Tags: jquery, orientation, screen-orientation, device-orientation

I'm working on a web app and it requires me to alter content based on the orientationEvent. It's working well so far, changing and setting content as I change orientation.  However, I need the orientationEvent to also fire at onLoad.  Is this possible?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var onChanged = function() { //TODO: Need to learn a way to fire it at load time
        if(window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90){
            $('#nav').html('<b> : LANDSCAPE : </b>');
        }else{
            $('#nav').html('<b> : PORTRAIT : </b>');
        }
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
 $(window).bind(orientationEvent, onChanged);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var onChanged = function() { //TODO: Need to learn a way to fire it at load time
        if(window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90){
            $('#nav').html('<b> : LANDSCAPE : </b>');
        }else{
            $('#nav').html('<b> : PORTRAIT : </b>');
        }
        event.stopPropagation();
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).bind(orientationEvent, onChanged);
}).bind('load', onChanged);
```